# How can we share individual rules between .drl files in JBoss Rules?

Tags: drools, modularization, jboss-rules

We are using [JBoss Rules](http://www.jboss.org/drools/) (a.k.a. Drools) and have several *.drl* files that each contain several rules. Is there a way to avoid duplication between files, so that we can define common rules that are available to more than one *.drl* file?

Unfortunately, there does not seem to be any kind of *include* or module facility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way of including rules from another .drl file from within a .drl file.

You can however add two .drl files to the same ruleBase and they will work as if they were in the same file.

```
PackageBuilder builder = new PackageBuilder();
builder.addPackageFromDrl( new InputStreamReader( getClass().getResourceAsStream( "common.drl" ) ) );
builder.addPackageFromDrl( new InputStreamReader( getClass().getResourceAsStream( "rules1.drl" ) ) );
RuleBase ruleBase  = RuleBaseFactory.newRuleBase();
ruleBase.addPackage( builder.getPackage()  );
```

Comment: This answer was correct at the time it was written, but PackageBuilder was removed from Drools 6.1. See related question: [PackageBuilder not available in drools 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27036793/packagebuilder-java-not-available-in-drools-6-1-0-final)