# PackageBuilder.java not available in Drools 6.1.0.final

Tags: drools

I am new to drools and we are currently using Drools 5.4.0 in our project.
Currently we are using RuleCompiler.java and PackageBuilder.java classes of Drools 5.4.0 to compile the .xls files and create ruleSetObject. The code snippet is as given below

```
String drlFromFile = null;
if (Pattern.matches(regexPattern, file.getName())) {
    if (file.getName().contains("csv") || file.getName().contains("CSV")) {
        drlFromFile = RuleCompiler.compileCSV(file);
    } else {
        drlFromFile = RuleCompiler.compileSpreadSheet(file);
    }
    if (drlFromFile == null || drlFromFile.isEmpty()) {
        logger.debug("Unable to Compile Rule Sheet: " + file.getName());
        throw new DroolsParserException("Unable to Compile Rule Sheet: " + file.getName());
    }
    PackageBuilder builder = new PackageBuilder();
    builder.addPackageFromDrl(new StringReader(drlFromFile));
    Package ruleSetObject = builder.getPackage();

    // Registering the compiled drl object in ruleExecutionSetRegistry
    ruleExecutionSetRegistry.registerRuleSetObject(file.getName(), ruleSetObject,
                    getRuleEngineProviderName());
}
```

Now we need to upgrade to Drools 6.1.0.final, but I can not find the PackageBuilder.java class there. I tried to search for its replacement but didn't get anything.

Is any new class has been introduced in place of PackageBuilder.java? Does any one guide me how to use that class?

Answer (score 1):

The 'new' way to do things is by defining a `KieModule`. Essentially, you create a Maven project which wraps your Drools rules, and then add that project as a dependency for your runtime. Generally, this expects that you will [follow certain conventions](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.1.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#d0e461) in how you structure your project so that Drools can find your rules itself.

However, you may (like me) find it easier to migrate without completely restructuring your existing project. To achieve this, you can still build up a `KieService` (the new `KnowledgeBase`), by adding files to a `KieFileSystem`. Here's a rough example of doing that:

```java
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();

KieFileSystem kfs = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
kfs.write(ResourceFactory.newFileResource(resource.getPath()));

KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kfs).buildAll();
if (kieBuilder.getResults().hasMessages(Level.ERROR)) {
    // It didn't build. Do something about it...
}

KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices
        .newKieContainer(kieServices.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId());

KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
```

And you're pretty much ready to go. In case it's useful, a recent demo project of mine contains [an example of doing this for plain .drl files](https://github.com/gratiartis/qzr/blob/cf0165b59449b5b6cb08d45fda5148c4dbfff709/qzr-rules/src/main/java/com/sctrcd/qzr/rules/HealthQuizKieConfig.java), and from what I understand, it should be pretty much the same if you want to add a spreadsheet to the `KieFileSystem` instead of DRL.

Comment: Hi Steve,

Thanks for the information. I will try to migrate without much restructure, as you suggested. I tried to open the link you gave for the demo project, but it shows 404 error.

Comment: Link corrected to point at the specific commit where that code existed. Last night I did a little refactoring to move to a convention-based approach to rules loading, which involved removing that class. :-/

Comment: Thanks Steve for the updating the link. Your demo project is very neat and clear. I have one more question. I want to keep my project JSR94 compliant. I can see the drools-jsr94-6.1.0.Final.jar in the Drools 6.1.0.final binaries. But I couldn't find any example of using it. Could you please guide me for the same.

Comment: I can't help with that ... I stay well away from JSR94, as it serves no useful purpose. It's also long dead as a standard, so you would have difficulty finding any examples of anybody using it. The Drools team have been considering removing support for a while.