# Include new .drl file from a DRL rule

Tags: include, drools

I want to load a new drl file based on the "when then " condition of some rule. In the following example i want to include a new  "checkMasterData.drl"  file when getFilteredMasterData().size()>3 from the another drl file

```
rule "Check for mouse catch"
  dialect "java" 
when
  $notification:NotificationVO(getFilteredMasterData()!=null
 ,getFilteredMasterData().size()>3);
then
  #include checkMasterData.drl
```

end

is it possible? Or do i need to do this from the java code after the fireall is succes of the first drl file

Comment: Very likely, this is not a good idea: you'll need to create a new session with everything that goes with it. - Please describe the *problem* you need to solve before discussing a technical solution.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you cannot include drl file from another , but you can do so programatically  .. as per this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91917/how-can-we-share-individual-rules-between-drl-files-in-jboss-rules) the following code can be use to merge 2 drl files to the same ruleBase and works as if they were in the same file.

```
PackageBuilder builder = new PackageBuilder();
builder.addPackageFromDrl( new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream( "common.drl" ) ) );
builder.addPackageFromDrl( new InputStreamReader( getClass().getResourceAsStream( "rules1.drl" ) ) );
RuleBase ruleBase  = RuleBaseFactory.newRuleBase();
ruleBase.addPackage( builder.getPackage()  );
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.